# Get the latest WHOLE record by date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

I have a collection with objects (records of events) like this:

```
{_id: 1, type: "A", val2: "x", val3: "z", date: 1/1}
{_id: 2, type: "A", val2: "y", val3: "y", date: 2/1}
{_id: 3, type: "C", val2: "z", val3: "x", date: 3/1}
{_id: 4, type: "B", val2: "x", val3: "z", date: 4/1}
{_id: 5, type: "C", val2: "y", val3: "y", date: 5/1}
{_id: 6, type: "B", val2: "z", val3: "x", date: 6/1}
```

I would like to fetch the *complete object* for the latest date for each type, so in the example above it should return records with ids: 2, 5, 6

I'm doing a pipeline query like this:

```
db.items.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$type",
           lastDate: { $last: "$date" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

but that returns me only documents like this:

```
{ _id: 2, lastDate: 2/1}
```

Whereas I want the *entire object* (with val2, val3, etc)

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this for specific items

```
db.items.aggregate(
 [
   {
     $group:
       {
         _id: "$type",
         lastDate: { $last: "$date" },
         val2: { $last: "$val2" },
         val3: { $last: "$val3" }
       }
   }
 ]
)
```

Note that you should use `ISODate` as the type for date and time fields.

Comment: exception: the group aggregate field 'val2' must be defined as an expression inside an object

Comment: @AndresQ: but I think you get the picture.

Comment: but this will set val2 to the last of all the val2, instead of the corresponding val2 of the original document

Answer (score 1):

As per **Markus W Mahlberg** answer first you should change your `date` type to `ISODate` or `timestamp` and then use aggregate. First sort `date` and group then like below query

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$sort":{"date":-1}},
                      {"$group":{"_id":"$type","lastDate":{"$first":"$date"},
                      "val2":{"$first":"$val2"},"val3":{"$first":"$val3"}}})
```